# Is there any docker image retention policy?

Tags: docker

We build lots of docker images which adds to disk usage. Is there any docker image retention policy out of the box which I can opt for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker does not have anything like that configured out of the box. There are commands to purge and prune unused images, containers and all that on the command line but there is no machinery to execute them frequently. Also, they may be either a bit hungry with deleting stuff or soft for your particular needs. As an example, you can filter containers to be removed if they were created more than a day ago:

```
docker container prune --filter "until=24h"
```

The caveats are up to you however. It is very likely that the front-end load balancer was created a year ago and only the configuration changed. Or what if it migrated to another host two weeks ago?

Many people have solved this problem for their needs and there are some pre-existing solutions. There are guides of varying quality available, mostly listing the required commands.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `docker image prune` command to remove unused images. 
To remove all images which are unused we can use command `docker image prune -a`.

Comment: I tried `docker image prune` and it shows `WARNING! This will remove all dangling images.` What does it mean by **dangling** ? I mean how does it know which image is unused ?

Comment: Images not being depended on by any of the existing containers. That includes locally built untagged images. Simply, docker traverses the list of layers that are part of an existing containers and removes the ones that were not met.